# Limitar cantidad de inserciones a una tabla por día

Tags: sql, vb.net

¿Hay alguna forma de evitar realizar mas de 10 inserciones por día y al mismo tiempo me muestre la cantidad de inserciones disponibles?

Me dijeron que lo intente con un procedimiento almacenado, y eso es lo que intenté hacer:

```
create procedure spinsertar
@usu varchar(50),
@con varchar(50)
as
declare @contador int
set @contador = 0
if @contador < 10
    -- consulta de insercion
    set @contador = @contador + 1
else
print 'Se acabo los limites'
select @contador
```

Pero no funciona, ¿alguna otra forma de hacerlo? Si lo hago dentro de la misma aplicación, ¿podría vulnerarse cerrando y abriendo la aplicación?

Como idea pienso archivo local .txt donde mantenga el conteo de registros y la fecha en la que se realizan, pero aun no se como hacerlo y no se si sea la mejor opción.

¿Alguna idea o ejemplo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Para orientarte mejor sería bueno que indiques a que base de datos apuntas.

Comment: Según lo que veo del procedimiento almacenado, en ningún lugar guardas el contador, por lo que hagas lo que hagas nunca podrás saber cuantos registros tienes guardados. Lo que se me ocurre es que te crees una tabla temporal y que conforme guardes cada registro, guardes el ID del registro  y si necesitas algún dato más. Entonces antes de insertar algún dato, compruebas el número de registros guardados en la tabla temporal.

Comment: Otra cosa que se me ocurre es que si quieres, además del ID te guardes el día y así podrás tener una cuenta de en cada día cuantos registros has guardado. Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer es una búsqueda por la fecha del día en que estés.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu procedimiento almacenado(`SP`) no funciona acorde a lo que quieres ya que cada vez que llamas a tu `SP` la variable `@contador` es 0 ya que esta es definida en cada llamada.

Para conseguir lo que quieres deberás almacenar esa variable en algún sitio además de que tendrás que borrarla cada X tiempo de acorde a tus especificaciones.

Una posible solución es:

1 - Crear tabla para guardar( Nombre de la Tabla, Nº inserts realizados, DiaInsercion date)
2 - Crear `SP` para controlar los registros insertados y insertar o no deacorde a tus especificaciones.

La implementación de estos pasos podría ser algo como:

Si trabajamos con la base de datos `Pruebas`

Creamos la tabla en la BBDD:

```
create table LimiteInserciones (NombreTabla varchar(60), NumInserts int, DiaInsercion DateTime)
```

Creamos el `SP` para la inserción

```
create procedure spinsertar
@usu varchar(50),
@con varchar(50)
as
declare @contador int,
 @hoy date

set @hoy = CONVERT(date,getdate())
set @contador = -1
select top 1 @contador = LimiteInserciones.NumInserts from LimiteInserciones
where LimiteInserciones.dia = @hoy && LimiteInserciones.NombreTabla ='nombreDeTablaDondeINsertemos'

if @contador = -1
begin
    insert LimiteInserciones Values('nombreDeTablaDondeINsertemos', 0, @hoy)
    set @contador=0
end

if @contador < 10
begin
    -- consulta de insercion
    update LimiteInsercionses
        set NumInserts = NumInserts +1
        where LimiteInserciones.dia = @hoy && LimiteInserciones.NombreTabla = 'nombreDeTablaDondeINsertemos'
end
else
    print 'Se acabo los limites'
return @contador +1
```

Luego simplemente deberíamos usar el `SP` para hacer las inserciones

PD: EL SP lo he hecho de "memoria" por lo que igual habría que modificar algún error de sintaxis